# Allow remote access to Database

Tags: python, sql-server

My problem: My team is writing  a program in python and, locally, I have a db (let's call it test.db) on SQL SERVER. So I have the following code:

```
    connection = pypyodbc.connect( "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;trusted_connection='yes';DATABASE=test")
```

My issue now, is my teammates need to use my Database. All I've found online is how to allow access to my DB through Management Studio ( so allow TCP/IP and allow port 1434)

I would like to have something like this

```
    connection = pypyodbc.connect( "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="My ip address" ;trusted_connection='yes';DATABASE=test")
```

Is this possible? ( where my ip address = some kind of number)

I was thinking of installing a server that listens for incoming connections but I've never really done this so I was wondering if there was another way to go about this.

Comment: SQL Server listens on TCP port 1433 by default, UDP port 1434 is needed when you connect to a named instance of SQL Server by instance name (e.g. `SERVER=YourPC\SQLEXRESS`. Run SQL Server Configuration Manger to make sure TCP/IP is enabled and the port number. Don't forget firewall.

Comment: so whenever my teammates want to connect through their python code they would put server = "pepePC"\SQLEXPRESS even if im not using express?

Comment: No, they would just specify "pepePC" to connect to your default instance. No need to worry about UDP 1434 in that case.